# Does MimeKit have a way to decompose cid: references?

Tags: mimekit

Does MimeKit have a canonical method to decompose the `cid:` references in a Mime message? Given an HTML email with e.g. an img src path of `cid:somefile.png@AUNIQUEID` I'd like to extract the `somefile.png@AUNIQUEID`.  I thought there might be an equivalent to `MimeUtils.ParseMessageId()` but can't see an obvious one.  I know it's a trivial string operation but wondered if there was a library function to remove the potentially error-prone manual step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MimeKit just uses the System.Uri class internally for that.